# Highlighting a page in an index

Tags: indexing

I would like to highlight one entry in an index.

If I have an index that appears several times in a document I would like to highlight one of these entries as the main one.

Something like

> My Entry, 2, 4-5, **10**, 15

Where page 10 is the *main* one.

Is there an easy way?

**Edit**

I am using `imakeidx` with several indexes. Something like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,twocolumn,openany,justified,nomultitoc,bookmarksopen=true]{dndbook}

% nomultitoc is needed if the list of figures is not displayed
% the multitoc package need the lof,lot,loc options (and from version to version it seems not to work)
\usepackage[toc,lot,lof]{multitoc}

\usepackage[]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=Persone,title=Persone e mostri,intoc]
\makeindex[name=Luoghi,title=Luoghi,intoc]
\makeindex[name=Oggetti,title=Oggetti,intoc]

\indexsetup{noclearpage}

\begin{document}

Bla bla\index[Persone]{My Entry} bla bla

% [...]

Bla bla\index[Persone]{My Entry} bla bla

% to correct the PDF links
\phantomsection
\printindex[Persone]

% to correct the PDF links
\phantomsection
\printindex[Oggetti]

% to correct the PDF links
\phantomsection
\printindex[Luoghi]

\end{document}
```

But I am open to other options

Comment: Which index package are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing of bold entries in the index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232752/placing-of-bold-entries-in-the-index)

Comment: @RüdigerVoigt Actually the linked answer is about ordering the bold entries first.

Comment: @Matteo:... which includes code how to highlight an entry. However, I have to admit that the answer by Peter Wilson is cleaner / better code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your main page:

```
\index[Persone]{My Entry|textbf}
```

will print the page number in the index in bold, whereas on other pages

```
\index[Persone]{My Entry}
```

will print a normal page number.

Comment: I tried but it just prints `My Entry, 10,textbf20,20` if the entry at page 20 is marked with `\index[Persone]{My Entry|\textbf}`

Comment: In your answer I see `|\textbf` with the unnecessary `\`. If I try to edit it, the `\` is not there.

Comment: @Matteo Sorry, my typo, which I have corrected. It should have been just `textbf` not `\textbf`.

Comment: OK I tried to edit it, but my browser showed a cached version :-)